# How can I build fdupes from source on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, apt, package-management, compiling, source

I would like to make a few changes to the fdupes code. I know I can grab the source code from the website - but is there a better way on Ubuntu / Debian?

- After getting the source this way where is it stored?
- If one wanted to make changes to the code and recompile / install - how is that done?
- Is there a good way to mange changes when updates come out?

Comment: Hiding version numbers from users will not improve security (but may decrease yours if it causes users to hunt you down because they want to punish you for the inconvenience).

Comment: ...especially with security-sensitive software like OpenSSL.

Comment: If you have to ask this question, it is a near certainty that any changes you make to SSL will break its security. Look for another way to accomplish what your goal is.

Comment: You don't change the question because you don't like the answers. Open a new question if you are truly interested in fdupes. Otherwise, you make the answers nonsensical.

Comment: @msw - focus on the question and not the motivation. it is a legitimate question - regardless of the reason it is being asked. I edited the question to make the focus more clear. it is also my question so stop editing it.

Comment: Why would you edit the question to not refer to OpenSSL anymore, but accept an answer that's OpenSSL-specific?

Comment: Lacking an answer, I'm reverting it, because the accepted answer makes no sense

Comment: @MichaelMrozek - updated the question and answer. The answer isn't great to start with by SX standards because it doesn't provide a lot of instruction and simply links to another webpage. If you would like to discuss this further can you send me a message? Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There sure is:

```
apt-get source fdupes
```

Have a look [here](http://wiki.debian.org/BuildingAPackage)